# trigger click on element loaded by ajax

Tags: jquery

how can i trigger click method of an element loaded by ajax runs on click event of a parent element?

i want it happen of page load time.

Comment: what do you mean by "i want it happen of page load time."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To trigger an event handler using jQuery:

- [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)
- [.triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

Could look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mybutton').trigger('click');
});
```

** edit **

After reading your comment, you can use jQuery's `.live()` or better `.delegate()` method to have a "live binding" on current and new elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mybutton').live('click', function() {
       // do something
    });
});
```

Ref.: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: thanks Andy,but i want trigger feature added elements.for some divs that my ajax adds to page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use .live() method. for more details look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/live/) link.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem in my experience.

**My solution is this.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#element_id").bind('click',function(){
alert('click event is triggered');
});

$("#element_id").trigger('click');
});
```