# simulate click on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to simulate click on dynamically appended element. But the code i used does not work. I don't know how can I move forward with my script. I used `.trigger()` method on load event of window. It does not work.

Code:

```
$( function() {
    $.post("ajaxify.php", "name=Heart", function(html) {
        $("#menu ul").append("<li>"+html+"</li>");
    });
});
$(window).load( function() {
    $("#menu ul li").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: When is the dynamic element added and when do you want to simulate the click on it? Right now you're trying to simulate a click on an element that doesn't exist as soon as the page loads, which obviously isn't correct.

Comment: How does the code look that appends the elements dynamically?

Comment: it's always a good idea to open the console (F12) and see if there are any errors. A jsFiddle would help too

Comment: An ajax request is sent and data is received on which some validation process occurs then the `<li>` is added to a div with validated data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [trigger click on element loaded by ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487817/trigger-click-on-element-loaded-by-ajax)

Comment: When you added the div to page, then trigger the click for it right after that.

Answer (score 3):

When adding your new 'li' elements to the menu, you can trigger a click on just that one list element:

```
$('<li />').text('My text here').appendTo('#menu ul').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code to simulate the click is correct, but it's being called at the wrong time. The code inside the function passed to `$(window).load()` is executed once when the window has finished loading, and will only effect elements that exist when the code is executed (so not your dynamically added ones).

You'll simply need to call that line of code after you've added the dynamically added elements, so at the end of the `success` callback function for your AJAX call.

To save you from modifying your existing code it may - if it's the only AJAX request being submitted on the page - be possible to use the `ajaxSuccess` event to trigger the click:

```
$(document).on('ajaxSuccess', function() {
    $('#menu ul li').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: oh you gave me an awesome idea!

Comment: This will trigger `click` for all `#menu ul li` again and again, not only the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

best contender for this scenario is 'on' method. which works well with dynamically added elements

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'ul li' function() {  // ul li is the context passed to the funciton
 //do something
});
```

Comment: That's not event delegation and will therefore be useless for dynamically added elements. They're also asking about triggering the click event programmatically, not binding the handler (though they may not be doing that correctly either, hard to know from the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery's `on()` method to register your events for a certain element in the DOM.